# Grails - DataTables plugin doesn't exist any longer?

Tags: grails, plugins, datatables

I tried to add --compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.14"-- and also
--compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.15" but none of them where found.

I want to use it with GRAILS-4.0.3 but it doesn't seem possible, is it abandoned in grails?

Ok, I tested with the new URL:s. Not sure if I did it correctly but it failed.

```
Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.15.Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/Lars/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/grails-datatables-0.15.pom

file:/C:/Users/Lars/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/grails-datatables-0.15.jar
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/grails-datatables-0.15.pom
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/grails-datatables-0.15.jar
https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugin-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/grails-datatables-0.15.pom
https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugin-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/grails-datatables-0.15.jar
```

It looks like I did it correct but it did not find it on the given URL.

build.gradle Looks like this in the beginning:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.2"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "test"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugin-releases-local" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.12'
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.15"
```

Gradle.properties looks like this:

```
grailsVersion=3.3.0
gormVersion=6.1.6.RELEASE
gradleWrapperVersion=3.5
```

But at this link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails.plugins/grails-datatables/0.15

I found a repository that worked:

```
Note: this artifact is located at Grails Plugins repository (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to add --compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.14"--
> and also --compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.15" but
> none of them where found.

You have not indicated which repositories you attempted to resolve those from, but those are available:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails.plugins/grails-datatables/0.14

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails.plugins/grails-datatables/0.15

https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.15/

https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/grails-datatables/0.14/

> I want to use it with GRAILS-4.0.3 but it doesn't seem possible, is it
> abandoned in grails?

As far as I know there is not a version of the plugin that is compatible with Grails 4.0.3.  The plugin is of course open source (https://bitbucket.org/ben-wilson/grails-datatables/src/master/).

Comment: I tested that but still failing.

Comment: If you are testing with Grails 4, I would expect it to fail.  As I said in the answer, as far as I know there is not a version of the plugin that is compatible with Grails 4.0.3.

Comment: Well I changed to 3.30 when I tested.

Comment: "Well I changed to 3.30 when I tested." - That plugin looks like a Grails 2 plugin.

Comment: What do you mean with "Grails 2 plugin"?? I looks for datatables-0.15 which should be the latest - how could that be a Grails2-plugin?

Comment: "how could that be a Grails2-plugin" - The plugin was built with Grails 2.5 and built for Grails 2.  We wrote a new plugin system for Grails 3 which is incompatible with Grails 2.  You cannot use a Grails 2 plugin in a Grails 3 project.  You also cannot use a Grails 2 plugin in a Grails 4 project.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me how I could verify which version of grails the plugin is for? The reference "datatables-0.15" doesn't say anything about that. And if it's not found, how can you tell what  grails version it is for? I have found a repository, added at the end of my question, that contained this plugin but how can I be sure it's the correct version?

Comment: The latest version in the repo I linked is built with Grails 2.5.3 (https://bitbucket.org/ben-wilson/grails-datatables/src/4d245835158debe69506123ffcd5de70eaa9b526/application.properties#lines-3).

Comment: The plugin has a Grails 2 plugin descriptor (https://bitbucket.org/ben-wilson/grails-datatables/src/4d245835158debe69506123ffcd5de70eaa9b526/GrailsDatatablesGrailsPlugin.groovy#lines-1).

Comment: The repos I linked above show a Grails 2 plug-in descriptor and a `.zip` file containing the plugin.  Only Grails 1 and 2 plugins are distributed that way.  Specifically, Grails 3 and Grails 4 plugins are not distributed that way.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work, the one from ben-wilson, It is however the only plugin version that could be found of all I tested. But the repositories you refered doesn't work for me so what is wrong the way I do it? If you look at my snap from my build.gradle, can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: "But the repositories you refered doesn't work for me so what is wrong the way I do it?" - As far as I can tell, those repos do work.  I can resolve dependencies from there.  I expect the problem you are having is you are trying to use the plugin from Grails 3 or Grails 4, which won't work.

Comment: "If you look at my snap from my build.gradle, can you see anything wrong with it?" - Yes.  Your `build.gradle` references `compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-datatables:0.15"`, which is not going to work because there is no Grails 3 plugin that satisfies that descriptor.  That line would work in a Grails 2 app in `BuildConfig.groovy` because a Grails 2 plugin does exist at those coordinates.

Comment: So the final sentence is that there is no working version of that plugin for grails3?

Comment: "So the final sentence is that there is no working version of that plugin for grails3?" - I don't know.  If anyone has ported the thing to Grails 3, they have not published it to our portal.  You could contact the author directly.  I think they may be in a position to know.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your patience offering all this time for this. I may try contacting the author otherwise develop a plugin for Grails4 by my self smells to be a bit over my skills but could be fun.